# Retrieve with groovy an Attribute value

Tags: groovy

I have the following data on groovy

> Binding Variables: [ timing:After Create,
> attributes:[**LOCK_OUT**:Attribute: {  **NAME**:Attribute:
> {Name=**NAME**, Value=[Bob]},   **PASSWORD**:Attribute:
> {Name=**PASSWORD**,
> Value=[org.identityconnectors.common.security.GuardedString@959e062c]}
> ]]

And I would like to retrieve the value of the password attribute  (the GuardedString ) with groovy but I am stuck in the last part.

Until now I did the following:

```
if (binding.variables != null) {
                
                    System.out.println("Binding Variables: "+ binding.variables );
                    
                    if(binding.variables.containsKey("attributes")){
                    System.out.println("Got Password binding variable" );
                    System.out.println (binding.variables.attributes.get("__PASSWORD__"));  //here it prints Attribute: {Name=__PASSWORD__, Value=[org.identityconnectors.common.security.GuardedString@3a6f394]}
        
                    System.out.println (binding.variables.attributes.get("__PASSWORD__").getAttribute("__PASSWORD__")); //this is not working..                         
                    
                    }
                
                    
                }
```

Can anyone help me? How can I retrieve this value?
Thanks

Comment: how woud you do it in java?

Comment: @injecteer I am actually confused because I have a list with map attributes inside?

Comment: @injecteer  I know it is simple but I am stuck

Comment: @injecteer I would most probably use getValue()

Comment: as per https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/identity-governance/12.2.1.3/omicf/index.html?org/identityconnectors/common/security/GuardedString.html you have to use `access(GuardedString.Accessor)` method to get a hold of the content of your string

Comment: @injecteer I was aware of the access (GuardedString.Accessor)

my problem is how to get the GuardeString from the attribute...

Comment: @injecteer
I wrote the following method
    public static String decrypt(GuardedString guardedString) {
     String[] clearText = new String[1];
     guardedString.access((clearChars) -> {
       clearText[0] = new String(clearChars);
     });
     return clearText[0];
    }

but I am having trouble of retrieving what should I put as a parameter

Comment: what's the type of `binding`? `groovy.lang.Binding`?

Comment: I retrieved this in the following way:

binding.variables.attributes.get("__PASSWORD__").getValue()

thanks!!

Comment: `binding.variables?.attributes?.PASSWORD?.value`